# How to use datetime instance as a timestamp in postgresql?

Tags: python, postgresql

I want to create postgresql function (`CREATE FUNCTION`) with PL/Python.

How do I convert from python `datetime` object to postgresql `timestamp` object in procedure?

Comment: "postgres function in python"? Huh? You want to access postgres from python? or use python to issue a  `create procedure`-type call to pg?

Comment: @MarcB yes, I want to create `stored procedure` in postgresql.

Comment: then you convert your python datetime to a format that PG accepts, and do the same in reverse with the results that PG outputs.

Answer (score 1):

Tell the `prepare` method the type of the parameter value, a `timestamp`, then pass a `datetime` value to the `execute` method:

```
create or replace function pytest()
returns timestamp as $$

    from datetime import datetime
    plan = plpy.prepare('select $1 as my_datetime', ['timestamp'])
    rv = plpy.execute(plan, (datetime.now(),))
    return rv[0]['my_datetime']

$$ language plpythonu;

select pytest();
           pytest           
----------------------------
 2016-07-20 13:57:59.625991
```

[Database Access from PL/Python](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpython-database.html)